# In knockout.js how can I remove detached ko.observables when my items array has been replaced?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a semi-complicated UI that among other things, keeps a running total of certain values the user inputs to make sure they add up to 100%. Since each data item itself is unaware of all of the other data items, I use a computed observable in the main model to handle this computation instead of an observable on the actual data item itself.

I noticed that even when the user filters the list (via ajax call), even if I replace the list with a single item, there seem to be computed observables hanging around relating to all the now missing items, I am guessing it is because I use a function to generate 'dynamic' observables.

I tried to use ko.cleanNode on my main 'table' but that just prevented it from refreshing at all. What is the proper way of dealing with computed observables in this scenario?

the View:

```
<span class="remainderText" data-bind="text:$root.getFieldTotal($data,'Customer')"></span>
```

The Model:

```
self.getFieldTotal = function (record, field) {
    return ko.computed(function () { 
                 .. some code here ...
            });
 }
```

When I go to replace the item array that drives the foreach, the computed observable fires off as if all the old items are still hanging around.

Comment: can you create a js fiddle to replicate this?

Comment: What is the purpose of returning a computed rather than just having a computed be a member of the item to which you are binding? I would guess this is the source of the issue. Need to see more code needed.

Comment: I created a fiddle for this at: http://jsfiddle.net/shuep/w8XpD/24/ the problem is the computeds I create as a result of the total method each still has a reference to the list, so even after the initial load and the subsequent search, the computeds are hanging around and getting called many more times than there are elements left.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to knockoutjs so I cant explain exactly why this works, but if you make your getFieldTotal method just a normal function, not ko.computed, then you get the behaviour you require. See this fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/PggQJ/1/